# Could not load NIB in bundle for _UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewController

Tags: uitextfield, ios8, nib, uialertcontroller

This:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                                                   message:message    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *tf) {
        tf.placeholder = @"email address";
    }];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                                                               }];
        UIAlertAction *upgradeAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Upgrade"
                                                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                                                               }];
        [alert addAction:cancelAction];
        [alert addAction:upgradeAction];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

is producing: 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle <....>  with name '_UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewController'' on iOS8.

However, if I remove the line of code that configures the text field, it works propertly.

Any thoughts on how I can remedy this? Thanks in advance.